# prove unitary variance of operator 2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose $\|.\|_2$ is induced by vector 2 norm s.t. $\|A\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$.

Suppose $P and Q$ are matrices with orthonormal columns(not necessarily orthogonal though). Say $P\in R^{p\times m}$, $Q\in R^{q\times n}$.
edit: $A\in R^{m\times n}$.

How do we prove that $\|PAQ^T\|_2 = \|A\|_2$. I think I can prove the case where $P, Q$ are orthogonal but it seems that the same proof does not hold for the more general matrices.

So I start with 
$\|A\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}((Ax)^TAx)^{1/2} = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}(x^TA^TAx)^{1/2} $.

And similarly,
$\|PAQ^T\|_2   = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}(x^TQA^TAQ^Tx)^{1/2} $. I will not be able to replace $Q^Tx$ with another unit value vector since it is not with norm 1.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(1) If $Q^T : \mathbb{R}^{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{k+l}$, then it is not
orthonormal.

Hence $Q^T : \mathbb{R}^{k+l}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $
P^T:\mathbb{R}^{k'+l'}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{k'}$ Here through
$Q^T$, image of a unit sphere contains unit sphere.

**Proof :** If $Q=[v_1\cdots v_k]$, then for $a=\sum_{i=1}^k\ a_iv_i,
 \ \|(a_1,\cdots, a_k)\|_2=1$, $$Q^Ta=(a_1,\cdots, a_k)$$

(2) Hence
$\|PAQ^T\|_2\geq \|A\|_2$.

**Proof :** $\| A\|_2$ is maximum of the map $$f:S'\times S\rightarrow
\mathbb{R},\ f(x,y)=\langle x,Ay\rangle $$ where $S',\ S$ are unit sphere in
$\mathbb{R}^{k'},\ \mathbb{R}^k$.

Here if $\| A\|_2=\langle y,Ax\rangle$, then $$\| PAQ^T\|_2\geq \langle P^Ty',AQ^T x'\rangle =\| A\|_2$$ where $P^Ty'=y,\ Q^Tx'=x$.

(3) In further note that image of a unit sphere is contained in unit ball so that we prove the converse.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why  the image of unit sphere through $Q^T$ contains a unit sphere? And also, how does that give $\|PAQ^T\|_2 \geq \|A\|_2$ ?

Comment: I add more explanation.